# Agglomerative Clustering and Support Vector Machines on Hadoop

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce, machine-learning, weka

I want to implement an Agglomerative clustering algorithm combined with Support Vector Machine. The way I want it to work is like this:

1. Train a support vector machine classifier with a large amount of training data. Keep the trained model aside. The training data is actually a large set of pairs of entities. Each entity is an array of numbers (double). The SVM classifies a given pair as either same/different.
2. Given a large set of entities (which are basically arrays of double values), find the two closest entities (arrays) by using the trained SVM to classify the pair of given entities as same/different. If they are same, then go ahead and cluster them.
3. Continue agglomerative clustering mechanism so long as we see that every entity in a cluster can be paired with every other entity in another cluster.
4. End the agglomerative clustering mechanism when we find that we have two clusters where there exists at least one entity in one cluster and another entity in the other clusters, which when given to the SVM will be classified as not-same.
5. Print/Store the output clusters in the output.

Now, I have done all this using WEKA's SVM and Agglomerative Clusterer on a stand-alone machine. When it comes to big data, I need to do this on top of Hadoop. I know of Mahout containing SVM, but it does not contain HAC.

i. Is it possible to use WEKA with Hadoop?
ii. How is it possible to store the trained SVM model in HDFS and then use it for agglomerative clustering if I plan to write a HAC in Hadoop myself? I am familiar with the Hadoop framework.

Comment: Don't think that mahout contains SVM.

Comment: Mahout does have SVM, infact very scalable.

Comment: According to https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/algorithms.html all three issues are solved as closed or won't fix. So I very much doubt there is one ;)